# Is there a pure Javascript X/HTML validator?

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I want to know if there's an existing Javascript library for validating HTML, preferably not one that relies on a web API.

The closest I've found to this is [John Resig's HTML parser](http://ejohn.org/blog/pure-javascript-html-parser/), but that seems to be more about fixing HTML and converting it to XML.

So is there something out there already? And if not, how difficult (and lengthy) would it be to adapt John Resig's parser?

Comment: http://philipwalton.com/articles/introducing-html-inspector/

Comment: how do I vote to undo the closing without editing the question, in case I find that the closing was pure and annoying nonsense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there isn't one. However I am writing one: https://github.com/peterjwest/html_validator

Comment: Great idea. I try to include it in Selenium IDE testcases to check validity of tested pages.
Is it a JS wrapper of tidy?

Answer (score -2):

You can't validate HTML with Javascript, because Javascript is loaded from within the HTML, which means the HTML is already rendered by the browser, which means all you can see with Javascript is the dom tree. The dom tree is built by the browser, but renders with and 'fixes' invalidations.

In short: What you need to validate HTML, is the HTML source. Javascript has access to the DOM, but not to the source.

**edit**
And immediately after posting, I'm thinking... You don't mean validating its own page =) You just want to validate a string with a javascript... So ignore this =)

Comment: That's actually a very good point, although I would have liked to validate the current page, validating a string is almost as good :P 

Is there any way round this? Like an XHR request to the same page?

Comment: That's a very good idea! That would have a string as result, which you can validate. But I can't help you with the actual validator... Too much string operations, regex and stacks. There must have been someone as mad as you to make a JS HTML validator =)

Comment: I've just got the source code for the w3c validator, its a 4000 line CGI script... now I just need to convert it to javascript :P

Comment: Haha good luck! You sure you want this!?

Comment: I gave up on their script, the W3C validator is rubbish anyway (I know it's technically accurate but the messages it gives are rubbish)!

Comment: It is rubbish and you should give up. I'm sure you have something better to do =) HTML validation is stupid anyway. If it works, it's perfect.

Comment: Guys why don't you construct and validate from PHP you can validate the JS also with the HTML and it's done there are tons of libraries and it works perfect with an Ajax solution.

Comment: Why don't you just delete this answer?

Comment: Because http://locustsandhoney.blogspot.nl/2009/10/once-its-on-internet-its-there-forever.html

Comment: Many issues that a validator would bring up are considered errors in XHTML, and will be immediately obvious*. If you have table>tr, HTML will* wrap the tr tags in a tbody, whereas XHTML will* leave it alone and perhaps not look quite right. Knowing this, you could write a validator in javascript for XHTML mode to check for proper nesting of elements and making sure required attributes are set, such as img[alt]. (*depending on the browser)