# Is there any Ruby tools or JavaScript libs to validate html is well-formed?

Tags: javascript, ruby, nokogiri, well-formed

I have tries to scraping html from URL by using '.errors' in Nokogiri but not working with

example:

```html
<table>
    <td></td>
</table>
```

And i don't know why return 'TRUE' as i thought is not a well-formed, Because the TRUE format must be like this

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The first example *is* well formed (all the tags are opened and closed in the right order and there is no use of implicit tags). It isn't valid though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809563/is-there-a-pure-javascript-x-html-validator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nokogiri only validates that your document is XML-valid. It doesn't validates it with the standards from the W3C.

You can use the gem [w3c_validators](http://code.dunae.ca/w3c_validators/) to validate the position of your html tags.