# validate html code purely with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, client-side

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a pure Javascript X/HTML validator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809563/is-there-a-pure-javascript-x-html-validator)

Is there a javascript library/framework that allows for validation of html code, without doing a server post back?

I'm looking for something similar to jslint/jshint, where you pass in the code, and it returns the error, line number, and message.

Comment: `innerHTML` always returns valid HTML, so you could normalise instead of validating.