# How can I check if a nested tag is allowed within it's parent tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If I'm adding a tag in JavaScript to another tag how can I check to see if it's valid.

IE I have this block:

Using JQuery:

`var fragment = $("<p>Some text is <strong>here</strong></p>");`

Is there a way using either JavaScript or some library to query this fragment and get a list of allowable tags?

For instance:

`fragment.wrapInner('<em></em>');`

Will generate valide HTML, but:

`fragment.wrapInner('<div></div>');`

Won't as div is not allowed inside a P tag.

The reason I want to do this is related to Range#surroundContents, as it's not letting me insert `span` tags directly inside divs, only insides `p` tags and the reverse is true as well, but I need a solution that will insert the correct type element inside the tag. IE `div` should not insert into `p` and the reverse, but these are far far from the only cases I need to concern myself with, as I'm dealing with generic content, so I need a general solution.

Comment: i don't think there's a list like that which you can pull from javascript, however you could just detect whether the element is display inline or not. If it's inline by default, it should be fine inside a p tag.

Comment: How about what's valid according to the spec? http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/

Comment: The problem is p is a block tag, but I need to know that it only supports inline tags inside. Check to see it's display type won't tell me I can't put a block inside it.

Comment: And I agree I don't think that list exists, unfortunately, but maybe there is a weird way to find it.

Comment: don't add tag that are not allowed since you are in charge of your script

Comment: That's the objective of my question.

Comment: @MattBall That won't really work as I need to do this at run time. The spec is loaded by the browser clearly, I want to see if I can check validation against the loaded spec, not parse it again (which is crazy and slow in JS).

Comment: Possible option: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809563/is-there-a-pure-javascript-x-html-validator

Comment: You have the semantics of `wrapInner()` wrong.  `fragment.wrapInner('<div></div>');` will put `<div></div>` around the contents of `fragment`, which is valid in the second case.  It's the first example which is invalid.