# How to check if an element is a valid child/parent for another element

Tags: javascript, html, children

Is there any way in JavaScript to check if a HTML element is a valid child of another element?

For example:

Can an unordered list (`<ul>`) accept a list item (`<li>`) as a valid child element? - **Yes**

Can an unordered list (`<ul>`) accept an unordered list (`<ul>`) as a valid child element? - **No**

---

Or is there any way to get a list of valid HTML children elements of a specific element?

For example:

Which elements are allowed to be children of a table row (`<tr>`)?
**Answer:** TD, TH

Which elements are allowed to be children of a span?
**Answer:** A, ABBR, ... (ALL)

Comment: Tags and elements aren't the same thing. Please don't use them interchangeably.

Comment: I don't know how to modify my question to match your observation.

Comment: i dont know if there is an easy solution but a solution could be to take the HTML DTD and store it in a JS Object, with for each key a tag and value is an array of permitted child tag

Comment: Very similar to [Is there a pure Javascript X/HTML validator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809563/is-there-a-pure-javascript-x-html-validator)

Comment: @animuson, you're so kind... thanks for your time spended editing my post!

Answer (score 1):

You can try creating the HTML in question and then validating it by this jQuery library:

https://github.com/peterjwest/html_validator

The demo.js is a good starting point:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var html = [
    "<title></title>",
    "<table><tbody></tbody><col></table>",
    "<tag><img apple=\"no\" banana='yes'></img></tag>",
    "<form action=''>",
    " <fish></fish>",
    " <fieldset>",
    " <img>",
    " <legend></legend>",
    " <legend></legend>",
    " <input>",
    " <!--</html><!-- :D -->",
    " </fieldset>",
    "</form>",
    "<table>",
    " <col>",
    " <tr>",
    " <td>",
    " </tbody>",
    "</table>",
    "<del><p>hallo</p></del>",
    "</body>",
    "<img>",
    "<img>",
    "<p><a></a></p>",
    "<form><fieldset><input type checked disabled='blah'></fieldset></form>",
    "</html>"
  ].join("\n");

  $.htmlValidator.doctypes;
  $.htmlValidator.doctype("HTML 4.01 Strict");
  $.htmlValidator.parseSettings();
  $.htmlValidator.parseSettings({});
  $.htmlValidator.parseSettings({url: ""});
  $.htmlValidator.parseSettings({html: html});
  $.htmlValidator.parseSettings({fragment: $("div")});
  $.htmlValidator.parse({doctype: "HTML 4.01 Frameset", html: html});
  console.log($.htmlValidator.parse({doctype: "HTML 4.01 Transitional", html: html}).call($.htmlValidator.fn.draw));
  console.log($.htmlValidator.validate({doctype: "HTML 4.01 Transitional", html: html}));

  //$.htmlValidator.parse({doctype: "HTML 4.01 Transitional"}); //Parses current page by AJAX with GET
  //$.htmlValidator.parse({doctype: "HTML 4.01 Transitional", type: 'post', data: {foo: 'bar'}); //Default loads current page by AJAX with POST
  //$.htmlValidator.parse({doctype: validator.doctype("HTML 4.01 Transitional"), html: html});
  //$.htmlValidator.validate();
  //$.htmlValidator.validate({fragment: $("#section").html()});
  //$.htmlValidator.validate({url: "/foo/bar"});
  //$.htmlValidator.validate({formatted: true});
  //$.htmlValidator.validate({formatted: false});
});
```

As you can see you can validate a fragment of the supplied page which is basically what you need.

As for checking the possible child elements I don't know if there is a good solution implemented.